# Can “along with” be used to mean “as a consequence of”?

Tags: grammar, editing

I have this sentence:

> Along with *something (cause)*, *something else (effect)* happened.

From text books I know that parts that are connected by “along with” should be in the same form and in the same category. What are the possible corrections for this sentence?

p.s. I need both meanings: *cause and effect* and *happening together*.

Answer (score 1):

No, "along with" means they happen together, perhaps having a common cause.

Correction:

> Because of *something (cause)*, *something else (effect)* happened.

Comment: What would you say to show that they also happened together?